# Working with GIT and VS 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

We installed VS 2017 on Windows Server 2016 and we want to use GIT for managing the changes.
After configuring GIT branches, it seems that 2 different users can't work on the windows server. When I change the branch, my colleague will see his branch changed as well.

Is there anyway to overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You’re using the same work folder? That will be a problem. Using separate folders? Will have no problems.

Comment: The default Git folder is under `\Users\<YourName>\Source`, for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

The normal expectation of any VCS is that each person has their own working area.

The working tree of git (or workspace of TFSVC) is individual. You then share by committing code and pushing to a shared repository. This allows individuals to work on different parts of the system without breaking the other until that piece of work is complete.